# Symfony2 changing Resources directory structure in a Bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2 in a project and I'm stuck with a problem.

I have to change the directory structure of the Acme/MyBundle/Resources to something different.

#### Usually it looks like:

- config
- doc
- public

  - css
  - images
  - js
- translations
- views

  - Controller1

    - index.html.twig
  - Controller2

    - index.html.twig
  - Controller3

    - index.html.twig

---

#### But it should look like:

- config
- doc
- pages

  - page1

    - public

      - css
      - images
      - js
    - translations
    - views

      - index.html.twig

---

### Explanation

This bundle is for rendering,managing,processing completly different pages. Different design, language, forms, javascripts, purposes. These are usually single pages. Questionaries.

It's working fine, I use one controller to render all of them and to proccess the data, but I currently use 5 questionaries, in the "old" directory structure, and it's getting more difficult to maintain every time I add one more.

I think it could make more sense to keep the parts of the questionaries together, it's easier to add, delete or edit.

### Question

- How do I render twig templates on their new place? (The render method looks for them in the Resources/views/)
- How do I make translations work?
- How to use assetic to dump files from their new place to my public web folder?

Thanks